# Find statement with alias

Tags: postgresql, cakephp

I'm trying to group a query's response by day, month, or year based on user input.

To do this I'm extracting the day, month, or year from the `log_time` column `AS when` and then trying to `GROUP BY when` but CakePHP says:

`SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "when" LINE 1: ...2-31' GROUP BY "Passenger"."route_id", "Route"."name", when ^`

Here's an example of my function call where the grouping is 'month'.

```
$fields = array(
    "CONCAT(DATE_PART('year', \"Passenger\".\"log_time\"), '-', DATE_PART('month', \"Passenger\".\"log_time\")) AS when", 
    "Passenger.route_id", 
    "Route.name", 
    "SUM(Passenger.embarked) AS embarked"
    );
$conditions = array(
    "Passenger.log_time >=" => $start, 
    "Passenger.log_time <=" => $end
    );
$group = array("Passenger.route_id", "Route.name", "\"when\"");

return $this->find('all', array('fields' => $fields, 'conditions' => $conditions, 'group' => $group));
```

This is using Postgres on Cake 2.3.5. Has anyone else figured out how to do this?

Comment: Also try to use virtual fields as documented. this will reduce the complexity here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I updated my code to use virtual fields. It looks cleaner now, but the problem remains. I'm going to leave my question as it is for now.

Answer (score 1):

`when` is a keyword that is used with [`CASE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE). Looks like PostgreSQL can figure out that the `when` in your `select` is just an identifier but there isn't enough context to figure it out in the `GROUP BY`. I'd quote it in both places:

```
"CONCAT(DATE_PART('year', \"Passenger\".\"log_time\"), '-', DATE_PART('month', \"Passenger\".\"log_time\")) AS \"when\"",
```

and:

```
$group = array("\"when\"", "Passenger.route_id", "Route.name");
```

Comment: Even if I quote "when" in the GROUP BY, the quotes don't make it to the SQL, yielding this error: `SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "when" LINE 1: ...2-31' GROUP BY "Passenger"."route_id", "Route"."name", when ^` I've updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @MattL: I don't know what sort of shenanigans CakePHP is getting up to, maybe try using a non-reserved name instead of `when`.